# ubuntu 16.04: docker not syncing its directory with the host's directory

Tags: docker, volume, docker-volume

I am trying to run a docker container. This docker container contains a set of files inside a directory `/mnt`. I want this directory to be automatically copied to the host's machine `/mnt` directory, upon the creation of the container, and anything that will be changed in the container's `/mnt` directory should also be changed on the host's directory.

I am running this command: 
`docker run -d --restart always -v /mnt:/mnt <image name>`

What is happening is that, instead of the container's directory being copied to the host, the opposite is happening. The host's empty `/mnt` directory is being copied and overriding the container's `/mnt` directory.

Why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

Comment: Yes, when you mount host directory to container directory. Host and container directory is sync. Host container will overide container, then anything changed inside container will be overide host directory too

Comment: Ok, but I want the opposite to happen. I want what is inside the docker container to override what is on the host container

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be for you to design the container in a way that it did not create the data in the container, but used the mount /mnt instead.

But if you must, a standard volume may do what you want:

```
docker volume create hostmnt
docker run -d --restart always -v hostmnt:/mnt <image name>
```

After that you can do a shell script to copy or map the volume to wtv directory you want.

But my suggestion would be to `docker cp` the content, and redirect all data that need being saved to the host or to a data environment, if possible.